# ASP.NET Core MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm just a beginner in ASP.NET Core MVC and I do not understand why the `)` is underlined with red at the end of this line:

```
@Html.ActionLink(process.ProcessName, "Details", new { id = process.Id },)
```

This is my view:

```
@using System.Diagnostics
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}
<div>
    <h1>List</h1>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var process in this.Model)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(process.ProcessName, "Details", new { id = process.Id },)
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Even if I delete the `)` at the end of that row or move it away, it just does not want to work out.

My `ProcessController.cs` looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
    public class ProcessController : Controller
    {
        //GET Process
        public ViewResult List()
        {
            var processList = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                              select p;
            ViewData.Model = processList.ToList();
            return View();
        }

        //GET Process/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var process = (from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                           where p.Id == id
                           select p).Single();
            return View(process);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Just delete the comma `,` before your closing parenthesis: `@Html.ActionLink(process.ProcessName, "Details", new { id = process.Id })`. This is just a method call, with three parameters - that extra `,` would have meant a fourth parameter would be supplied - but there is nothing after the `,` - so that doesn't work .....

Comment: Then the whole row will be underlined with red.

Comment: Since something is showing red you're probably using an editor/IDE. There should be errors listed there, or the build step should explain it, or something. They don't communicate only by colors and underlines. Check what the error message says.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: If I write it this way                 @Html.ActionLink("process.ProcessName", "Details", new { id = process.Id })    then it works but here   https://localhost:7270/process/list  instead of I would see the ProcessNames I can see this in every row:    process.ProcessName          I can click on and then shows the details for example:   Registry
136                                                             (But sadly the list is not good because every row is the same process.ProcessName.)

Comment: Can you try typecasting process.ProcessName to string? Like (string)process.ProcessName...